# Android Vulnerability Exported activity=true

Tags: android, security, apk

I have an application that has only 1 activity "MainActivity" and it must be divided in fragments, because there are 3 windows, one of them is the user details, and this activity (the main activity) has exported=true.

I want to know if this entails a security flaw in an Android APK:

I log in the application
I start the activity with drozer: `run app.activity.start --component com.member com.member.MainActivity`
I can see the user details, but not in the first display, I need to press another tab, which must be another fragment inside the MainActivity.

Is it the normal behavior?
It is true that exported activities can be used by apps with a different uid, but the user must be logged in, which problem does it entail?

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the normal behavior?

If by "the normal behavior" you mean that exported activities can be started by third-party apps, then yes.

> It is true that exported activities can be used by apps with a different uid

If by "used" you mean "started", then yes.

For example, this activity of yours probably has this `<intent-filter>`:

```xml
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
```

This says "hey, anything that is a launcher, please include me in your roster of launchable activities!". The launcher is how most Android device owners start apps. If your activity is not exported, then the launcher would not be able to start your activity, and as a result the user will not be able to use your app.

Note that having an `<intent-filter>` on an `<activity>` automatically sets `android:exported` to `true` — you do not need to declare this manually.

Comment: Yes, my activity has that intent.
Now, to be more specific, this Activity, when launched and click on the correct fragment, has sensitive data.
How is this a vulnerability? Or it is not?

Comment: @aDoN: I do not have nearly enough information to be telling you whether something is or is not a vulnerability. Having an activity that can be started is not, in itself, a vulnerability. But, depending on the nature of the "sensitive data", you may need to consider your own in-app authentication mechanism, beyond anything supplied on a device. Banking apps, for example, usually do not show you your account information (balances, etc.) without some sort of authentication at the point of launching the app.